# Query to count frequency

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table of the form:

```
A 2 
A 2
A 2
A 2
A 3
A 4
A 4
A 4
```

I want output of the form:

```
A 2 3
A 3 1
A 4 2
```

*What will be the most efficient query for this problem ?*

Comment: Did you mean A 2 4, A 3 1, A 4 3?

Answer (score 4):

```
select col1, col2, greatest(count(*) - 1, 1)
from your_table
group by col1, col2
```

Comment: what is this greatest means here?

Comment: It means: Take which is greater - the count result-1 or `1`.

Comment: it should be an user defined function, right?

Comment: Confirmed: COUNT: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01f25/2, COUNT-1 OR 1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01f25/3

Comment: Greatest is a normal mysql function - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest